# Can Entity Framework be configured to drop/create schemas instead of entire database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 Code First to develop an app. It needs to integrate with an existing database (used by other applications).

I have some entities that map to tables that are in an existing "otherapp" database schema, and I am creating new entities that will exist in the "myapp" schema.

Creating the tables in the appropriate schema is no problem using a map (EntityTypeConfiguration).

Is there a way to have the DbInitializer drop and create entities in my "myapp" schema, but just verify the model against the "otherapp" schema entities?

Alternatively, is it difficult to have the initializer just create entities that don't exist, instead of only creating the DB if it does not exist?

Comment: I don't know of any inherently supported functionality for that - but you can always write your own migration scripts using `Sql()` in the migration files. I am not entirely following the question about creating entities: the migration to create entities will run only once (or are you dropping the tables outside of the application and want them automatically re-created)?

Comment: We will be pulling a database down from a higher environment to development environment, which may have different contents in the "myapp" schema to what my EF model contains, e.g. context.Database.CompatibleWithModel will return false. We're not using code-first migrations (out of my hands), and since we need to maintain the schema and data of "otherapp" in the database, I can't just drop/re-create on model change / always